# loopbackjs remote connector not returning ids

Tags: node.js, rest, loopbackjs

I have a nodejs application which is is trying to comunicate with a loopback server

I have the following datasources

```
{
    "db": {
        "name": "db",
        "connector": "memory"
    },
    "remoteDS": {
        "url": "http://localhost:3033/api",
        "name": "remoteDS",
        "connector": "remote"
    }
}
```

using `loopback-connector-remote`

I have `common/models/pack.json`

```
{
    "name": "pack",
    "plural": "packs",
    "base": "PersistedModel",
    "idInjection": true,
    "properties": {},
    "validations": [],
    "relations": {},
    "acls": [],
    "methods": {}
}
```

and my `test.js`

```
var app = require('./client/client');
app.models.Pack.create({foo: 'bar'})
    .then(result => {
        console.log(result); // { foo: 'bar', id: NaN }
        return app.models.Pack.find()
    })
    .then(result => {
        console.log(result); // [{ foo: 'bar', id: NaN }]
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err.message);
    })
```

I do not know why `id: NaN`

When I am trying via the api explorer I have the id

```
[
  {
    "foo": "bar",
    "id": "5bdaf67aed811700149e4549"
  }
]
```

Comment: Aren't you just creating a single instance with `foo` property only? `app.models.Pack.create({foo: 'bar'})`

Comment: @falinsky This is just a test, the id is automaticly generated in database but not returned

Comment: I believe you should provide more code. For example how do you declare your model `Pack`?

Comment: This is in `common/models/pack.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using as your `common/models/pack.json`

```
{
    "name": "pack",
    "plural": "packs",
    "base": "PersistedModel",
    "idInjection": false,
    "properties": {
        "id": {
            "type": "String",
            "id": 1
        }
    },
    "validations": [],
    "relations": {},
    "acls": [],
    "methods": {}
}
```

Loopback [adds the id property as a number](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Model-definition-JSON-file.html#id-properties), so it may be trying to parseInt your Id value on create.  Perhaps the REST connector is creating it and querying it?

> By default, if no ID properties are defined and the idInjection property is true (or is not set, since true is the default), LoopBack automatically adds an id property to the model as follows:
>
> id: {type: Number, generated: true, id: true}

Comment: Thanks https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-connector.html#using-with-mongodb-connector